# Make list view non scroll able inside a Scroll view

Tags: android, listview

I am using a scroll view in which I have many other views including two list views. I'm adding items dynamically to the lists. I want my scroll view to scroll, not the list views. How can I do this?

Here is my XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.social.socialapp"
 android:id="@+id/frgmentCreditSL"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="#000000"
 android:fillViewport="true"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:scrollbars="none" >

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#eeeeee"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Your total balance :" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/creditYourCredit"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|right"
            android:text="12"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.50"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:text="Daily free credit" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.70"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="50" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/creditClaimBT"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.80"
            android:background="#579df9"
            android:text="claim" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/note_TV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Note: Free credit expires in 14 days"
        android:textColor="#C0C0C0" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/creditPremiumTV"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.50"
            android:text="costs" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/creditPremiumMemberBT"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:background="#579df9"
            android:text="$ 1.99" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/creditAvailableOffersLV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" >
    </ListView>

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#777777"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Costs Table"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#777777"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Basic"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#777777"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Premium"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/PostCostLV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Help me plz i am stuck badly here

Comment: @:Dude You dont want to scroll the listview right, you just want to scroll whole layout not list.. am i right

Comment: disable this property of your list view listView.setScrollContainer(false)===> may be this can help.

Comment: yes thats what i want